# Building Custom Component for SceneBuilder (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls

I followed this blog [Adding a Custom JavaFX Component to Scene Builder 2.0](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/adding-custom-javafx-component-to-scene-builder-2-0-part-2/), and built my own Custom component.

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="400.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <HBox fx:id="border" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="400.0" styleClass="textbox-container" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="textbox-label" text="Label" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <HBox minWidth="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <TextField fx:id="textbox" prefWidth="176.0" styleClass="textbox" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button fx:id="clear" focusTraversable="false" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="button-controller" text="X" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Controller Class:

```
public class CellTextFieldClear extends AnchorPane {

    @FXML
    private HBox border;
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextField textbox;
    @FXML
    private Button clear;

    public CellTextFieldClear(){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/celltextfieldclear/CellTextFieldClear.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try{
            loader.load();
        }catch(IOException exception){
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void setOnActionHandlerForClear(EventHandler<ActionEvent> event){
        clear.setOnAction(event);
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean value){
        textbox.setEditable(value);
    }

    public String getTextFromTextBox(){
        return textbox.getText();
    }

    public void setTextBoxText(String text){
        textbox.setText(text);
    }

    public void setLableText(String text){
        label.setText(text);
    }

    public String getTextFromLabel(){
        return label.getText();
    }
}
```

StyleSheet:

```
.textbox {
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color:  white;
}

.textbox-label {
    -fx-background-color:  #b0c4de;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 5;
}

.textbox-container {
    -fx-border-color: #191970;
    -fx-border-width: 0.5;
}

.button-controller {
    -fx-background-radius: 0; 
    -fx-background-insets: 0; 
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.button-controller:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
        #ecebe9,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
        linear-gradient(#dcca8a, #c7a740),
        linear-gradient(#f9f2d6 0%, #f4e5bc 20%, #e6c75d 80%, #e2c045 100%),
        linear-gradient(#f6ebbe, #e6c34d);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0; 
    -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.1) , 2, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}

.button-controller:pressed {
    -fx-background-color:
        #ecebe9,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
        linear-gradient(#dac980, #c6a530),
        linear-gradient(#f8f0d4 0%, #f3e4ba 20%, #e0c050 80%, #e3c440 100%),
        linear-gradient(#f5fbae, #e7c94f);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0; 
    -fx-effect: innershadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.1) , 2, 0.0 , 0 , 1);
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Now my question is I cannot change the value of label from Scene Builder. Can we create a custom field which will appear on Scene Builder and which will help to change the Label Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have editable fields on Scene Builder, you should use properties. Otherwise, a `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` is used.

For instance these:

```
private final BooleanProperty editable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

public boolean isEditable() {
    return editable.get();
}

public void setEditable(boolean value) {
    editable.set(value);
}

public final BooleanProperty editableProperty() {
    return editable;
}

private final StringProperty textFromTextBox = new SimpleStringProperty();

public String getTextFromTextBox() {
    return textFromTextBox.get();
}

public void setTextFromTextBox(String value) {
    textFromTextBox.set(value);
}

public final StringProperty textFromTextBoxProperty() {
    return textFromTextBox;
}

private final StringProperty labelText = new SimpleStringProperty();

public String getLabelText() {
    return labelText.get();
}

public void setLabelText(String value) {
    labelText.set(value);
}

public final StringProperty labelTextProperty() {
    return labelText;
}
```

And then bind the controls to those properties:

```
public CellTextFieldClear(){
    ...

    textbox.editableProperty().bind(editableProperty());
    textbox.textProperty().bind(textFromTextBoxProperty());
    label.textProperty().bind(labelTextProperty());
}
```

[image: Custom control]